# Listview Image loading Using Aquery

Tags: android

I am using the android query library but it fails to load image in the listview,

So, is there and link or source code available to use the aquery and load the image in listview properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Onadapter(Context context,String[] id,String[] label,String[] title,String[] image,String[] hrs,String[] posted_date)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        this.hrs = hrs;
        this.posted_date=posted_date;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView img;
        TextView id;
        TextView label;
        TextView title;
        TextView hrs;
        TextView posted_date;

    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.whatslist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.id=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.whats_id);
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumb1);
            holder.label= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist_e_desc);
            holder.hrs = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hrs);
            holder.posted_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.id.setText(id[position]);
        holder.label.setText(label[position]);
        holder.title.setText(title[position]);
        holder.hrs.setText(hrs[position]);
        holder.posted_date.setText(posted_date[position]);
        imgaq = new AQuery(convertView);
        imgaq.id(holder.img).image(image[position], true, true, 0, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN_NETWORK, 1.0f);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return image.length;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
}
```